# Is self answering within the same minute an allowed behavior?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Consider this question: [how to convert enum between (string ,list of flags ,enum with flags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410350/how-to-convert-enum-between-string-list-of-flags-enum-with-flags)

The user asked this question at "2016-07-16 10:46:12Z" and self answered it "2016-07-16 10:46:12Z" -- *at the same second*. Is this even possible?

The question has its merits and the OP gave a good answer.

I would flag this for moderator attention, but I don't know if this behavior should be allowed/enforced, nor if Stack Overflow is supposed to work like a knowledge repository like this -- more suitable to CodeProject, for instance.

Comment: 41k and you didn't know about this?  Wow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, whenever you ask a question you can tick the checkbox **Answer your own question**. If you do so, the answer will be posted at the same time the question is posted.

[image]

This is - under certain conditions - acceptable and encouraged in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). There even is a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for a good self-answer. Of course, the question and the answer must comply to the Stack Overflow standards, just like they would if they were from two different users.

Answer (score 5):

> but I don't know if this behavior should be allowed/enforced

**This behavior is acceptable and must be allowed** as it's clear from the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) that:

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. ***If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question*** on a Stack Exchange site.