# Should we encourage self-learners more?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, self-answer

In the last few days, I posted multiple questions within the comparatively small [CodeDOM tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codedom). Due to the fact that the tag gets little attention, I often end up answering my own questions some days or weeks later when I finally find a solution after time-consuming trial and error. I also feel posting this on Stack Overflow might be helpful to future readers, particularly as official documentation is lacking or doesn't seem to answer some specific issues (that's why *I* look on Stack Overflow). This saves those readers from the same efforts.

In contrast, there are many questions that never ever get an answer. I assume at least some of those are eventually solved by the askers themselves, but it's not documented on Stack Overflow in any way and gets lost forever.

Wouldn't it be better to encourage askers more to answer their own questions if they found an answer? Of course there's the self-learner badge, but is it enough?

Comment: Do you have a specific idea in mind on how to encourage people to do that?

Comment: One simple would be to get the rep for the answer. However this might attract misuse. Maybe a silver-badge?

Comment: I *think* you can already get reputation for self-answers... it might be an idea to remind users (after, say, two weeks) that they can self-answer a question. The reminder could be shown only for questions that gained at least one upvote

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, you do get rep for self-answers. Both positive and negative. The only exception is accepting - you don't get 2 points for accepting your own answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it needs to be encouraged but I do understand that some feel discouraged to self-answer: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332694/are-self-answered-questions-still-encouraged-on-stack-overflow), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328057/is-self-answering-within-the-same-minute-an-allowed-behavior)

Comment: Maybe you ought to focus a bit more on proper tagging.  A tag like [codedom] always ought to be paired with [c#].  You are not going to have to wait long.  Not to discourage your effort, but the more SO users see a question, the higher the odds it gets a good answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I do so usually, however they all get only a few views and thus only a few votes. However the tag codedom may also be combined with vb, just for completeness.

Comment: Decide between C# and VB.NET tags by either what language the question's sample code is posted in, or what language you want code snippets in answers to be posted in. Don't use both just because the library has bindings for either language, unless you truly want answers to consider both languages. This won't, of course, guarantee upvotes. It is a well-known fact that less popular technologies don't get nearly the same activity and votes that more popular technologies do. This is a basic failure of a popularity-driven site, not something easily changed.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn´t want to mix both tags, I simply replied to HansPassant that not all questions tagged with codedom should also get the c#-tag.

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't it be better to encourage askers more to answer their own questions if they found one? Of course there´s the self-learner badge, but is it enough?

The system already encourages users to answer their own questions. There doesn't seem to be any more that we could do to encourage it than we already do. There are only two distinctions between self-answers and answers posted by others:

1. You do not earn the +2 acceptance bonus when you accept your own answer. This is to prevent abuse, and the logic is the same as why you cannot upvote your own answers.
2. There is a period of delay imposed between the time that you post a self-answer and the time that the system allows you to *accept* your self-answer. The theory behind this is that you should give other users adequate time to answer the question before deciding on which answer to accept, in case someone else has a better solution than you do.

I don't think either of these should be changed. You still earn reputation as normal when *other users* upvote your answers. I posted [this Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102565/how-can-a-vb-6-app-determine-if-it-is-running-on-windows-10) a while back because I still get a lot of activity on [a similar old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842632/366904), but updating that answer to work for Windows 10 would make it too unwieldy, so I just turned it into a new Q&A of its own. Naturally, I cannot upvote any of my own posts, but 4 people thought the question was useful (which earned me 5 reputation × 4 = 20 points), and 11 people thought the answer was useful (which earned me 10 reputation × 11 = 110 points). (Well, not necessarily, because I probably hit the reputation cap that day, but the point still stands.) There's plenty of *incentive* here to answer your own questions.

> [T]here are many questions that never ever get an answer. I assume at least some of those actually get one by the askers themselves after a while, however it´s not documented on SO in any way and gets lost for ever.

You're right, there are plenty of questions that get asked but never get an answer. I have a theory about why that is the case, though. The problem isn't that self-answers are insufficiently encouraged, the problem is the questions themselves.

You see, most of these questions that never get answers are actually [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The *real* answer to such questions is either "this is impossible," "you're going about it the wrong way", or both.

[image: That's not how this works! That's not how any of this works!]

Users typically don't post these types of answers because they are not popular with the community. Not only do they earn few upvotes, they tend to attract downvotes and flags. No one seems to like "don't do it" answers, even when they are the correct answer.

And the person who asked the question probably *does* eventually figure out a solution to their problem, but they typically arrive at this solution by punting the problem. [They still don't have an answer to the question that was asked, they only have a solution to the problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160902-00/?p=94235). That doesn't get posted as an answer for the same reason.

In my mind, what needs to change is the community presumption against "don't do it this way" answers. Or, one could argue that these questions are not useful because they contain erroneous assumptions and can never truly be answered. Not ever getting an answer serves as a signal to the [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) that the question should be automatically deleted.