# How should "impossible" questions be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've seen some questions that are well-written and high-quality, but are impossible because you simply can't do whatever the question is asking.

Example:

> **Q:** How do I modify a constant?

The only way I believe these questions can be answered is:

> **A:** You can't modify a constant. Use a variable instead.

But I don't feel these types of answers are appropriate, since they don't fully address/answer the question:

> **Q:** How do I make a **pig** fly all by itself without physically modifying it?
>
> **A:** You can't do that. Use a **bird** instead.

Okay, bad example, but you get what I mean.

How should "impossible" questions be handled?

Comment: Short, pithy answers belong in comments. :)

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem here is. If the question is whether or how to do something which can't be done, then the correct answer, assuming it's not actually an X/Y question, is to say that it can't be, hopefully with relevant explanation and/or pointers to documentation, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661306/can-i-use-es6s-arrow-function-syntax-with-generators-arrow-notation/27661420#27661420), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/deep-object-merging-in-es6-es7/34986585#34986585).

Comment: Not if they answer the question, @code. Short, pithy *comments* belong in comments, not *answers*.

Comment: See the *Toesy Socks* example on [jmac's excellent write-up of "too broad" on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> But I don't feel these types of answers are appropriate, since they don't fully address/answer the question

I cannot make sense of this claim. **Of course they do!**

If the question is "how can I do *x*", and the answer is "you cannot do *x*, do *y* instead", then that is a perfectly reasonable answer. In fact, it's a *good* answer and should be upvoted. A mediocre answer would be simply "you can't do *x*". It is correct and answers the question as far as it goes, but it doesn't quite go far enough. What makes your example a *good* answer is that it goes on to propose a reasonable alternative. It cannot get any better than this. Beyond simply answering the question, you have solved the person's problem!

You either encourage answers like this, or you close and delete the entire question. Those are the only two options. Since there's no close reason for "not possible", the only reasonable conclusion is that these types of answers are acceptable.

Related: [Should we encourage self-learners more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333876/should-we-encourage-self-learners-more/333924#333924) (coincidentally posted before I read your question)

Comment: Even better: _"You cannot do `X` because <explanation>, do `Y` instead"_. Also, such answers could prevent the question from being asked in the future, and provide a dupe target.

Answer (score 11):

### Handling X/Y Questions

You're describing X/Y questions. Using your example above, "How do I modify a constant?" is really an X/Y question where someone has decided that the *problem* that they have (whatever it is) can be *solved* by modifying a constant.

If the question is well-written and shows some research effort, it will generally be clear to experienced answerers that it's an X/Y question. Luckily, a well-written question will give you enough information to post some insightful comments, and sometimes even reframe the question in order to post a pragmatic solution.

If the question is poorly written, then you might not be able to tell what the OP is really trying to accomplish. In such cases, you can:

- Ask clarifying questions in the comments to invite updates to the original question.
- Read comments from the OP regarding other comments or answers to see if you can gain any insight into what they were really after.
- Vote to close the question for a suitable reason, or write in your own if it's a poor-quality question and no other close reason quite fits.

In my opinion, programming is more about how you conceptualize a problem than it is about finding the "one true answer." With that in mind, helping other users reframe a problem is really the first step in defining a workable solution that fits the use case. When it's an obvious X/Y problem, don't allow yourself to fall into the same trap that the OP did by overly constraining the solution space.

Answer (score -15):

> **Q:** How should “impossible” questions be handled?
>
> **A:** Down vote, vote to close and move on.

Comment: I'm curious: vote to close *as what*? Too broad? Nope; the question seems quite well specified. Off topic? Nope; it's perfectly on-topic. Opinion based? Nope. Unclear? No, it's perfectly clear what the OP wants. There is no "can't do it" close reason.

Comment: _"That's not possible because <foo>, use <bar> instead"_ is a perfectly good answer to questions like these. No need to close'm. In fact, such answers could prevent the question from being asked in the future.

Comment: 99% chance the same ridiculous question has been asked a dozen times already in one form or another, they are all almost guaranteed to be duplicates.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate is different then voting to close because it is an "impossible" question.