# Can I ask about CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, site-recommendation

I originally posted the following question at the Software Engineer Stack Exchange, because I thought it fit their "Software development methods and practices" clause for "what topics can I ask about here?" But the question was downvoted as off-topic for there.

Below is the text of my question -- **is it suitable for Stack Overflow?**

> I'm newly learning CMake and recently learned about CMake Presets.
> My question is basically: **how should you choose whether to set the CMake install prefix in CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt?**
>
> Context to my question:
>
> I am learning CMake (mostly from a Udemy course). In one of the lectures, the instructor was building Google Test, which is a CMake-based project. He set the install directory by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in his IDE (CLion).
>
> In my IDE, Visual Studio 2022, when I click on "Manage Configurations," the IDE generates CMakePresets.json, and in particular, it generates an `installDir` field, which has the effect of setting the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` cache variable. I.e. setting the CMake Presets field "installDir" would have the same effect as specifying a `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=..."` command-line argument or `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ...)` statement in a CMakeLists.txt.
>
> Because the IDE generated CMakePresets.json with the install prefix (instead of creating/editing CMakeLists.txt) I formed the notion that setting the install prefix in CMakePresets.json is preferred over setting it in CMakeLists.txt.
>
> Now, I would like the value of the install prefix to include the system processor, which is available in CMakeLists.txt as `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` (example value "x86_64"), but as far as I can tell from the CMake Presets documentation, there are no variables/macro expansions that have this value.
>
> Moreover, I find examples of people setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in their CMakeLists.txt, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481958/setting-cmake-install-prefix-from-cmakelists-txt-file).
>
> Basically, I am confused about whether there is any prevailing convention or best practice whether to set the CMake install prefix in CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt.
>
> Although my specific question is about the CMake install prefix, I wonder if there is a more general rule of thumb how to decide whether to set CMake cache variables in CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Unfortunately, NO. This is the epitome of an opinion based question which is specifically off-topic.

Comment: A question like "What is better, A or B?" always risks to be closed with "opinion-based" or such... but at the same time it is very possible for such problem to have well-known solution. Just ask the question and wait.

Comment: I'm not an SME but I suspect this could be edited into a "How Do I" question by stripping it down to the essential details of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "What is better. Quicksort or Selection Sort?" is not opinion-based unless you are.... a strange person and wrong.

Comment: Thank you to all commenters and answerers. Identifying that the answer to this question is opinion-based is actually an answer in and of itself, and is a useful addition to building my mental model of CMake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, Stack Exchange websites try to avoid unnecessary subjectivity; this effect is much stronger on Stack Overflow and on sites that deal with a technical topic.

> how should you choose whether to set the CMake install prefix in CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt?

We can't really tell you how to reason about problems (although we can explain some problem-solving techniques); we aren't interested in making lists of pros and cons that are a matter of taste; and we *certainly* aren't going to weigh pros and cons for you or make a decision for you.

But we *can* explain the foreseeable objective consequences of your choices.

Start with the context. Explain it *concisely* - don't give us a backstory of your thought process, but instead just make sure we can see where you are are now and what you're considering doing. Then try to ask a concrete question about that - and make sure we can understand why you don't just *try it and see*.

That said, after reading through your existing context, I'm not really clear on what the question is - because I'm not clear on *exactly what possible alternative actions* you're considering taking. For example, do you want to press something in the IDE and have it re-generate the `CMakePresets.json` file? Are you considering manually editing that file? (Are you worried about the IDE re-overwriting your change?) Exactly what change do you want to make? (Or is the question actually about what can be written into the JSON file to make the system work?) If you change it in `CMakeLists.txt` instead, again what change are you proposing to make exactly (you should show this as code)? Are you worried about having the same information in both files? Are you trying to ask about which takes precedence if the information is specified in both places? Are you considering deleting the information from the JSON file entirely?

Or just what?

Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then give a careful, clear presentation of what options you are considering. Again, first make sure that you can't get an answer by just **trying it**. If you try one or more options, and something doesn't work with one or more of them, then you can turn that into a question about why one approach isn't equivalent to the other, or about how to do it properly with whichever system you couldn't get working, etc. If it seems like some change that you made isn't having the expected effect, again you can make a minimal, reproducible example for the complete setup, explain what you think should happen, and ask why it doesn't.

Comment: I don't use VS, but I hope it has the sense to not kill something that a user wrote in a presets file- even if the presets file was initially generated by VS. If VS has some sort of GUI layering over the file, I assume it wouldn't be sophisticated enough to cover all of what a presets file can contain (sounds like a hard to maintain feature, especially given that the preset schema evolves over time), so I'd expect it to support and respect manual edits to the file. The whole point of CMakeLists.txt and CMakePresets.json is that they're the 1 thing you configure, then generate configs from

Comment: I generally want specific context instead of long-winded thought process and "backstory", but here, I actually think the way this question is expressed is better with the thought process instead of highly specific context. It causes the question to be generalized to a level that I find valuable for teaching. It gives a very clear picture of what the asker knows and understands, and what knowledge gaps probably need filling.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not concerned about this being an opinionated question, and honestly personally wouldn't classify it as one. I see this as a really good teaching opportunity.

Here is an example answer to demonstrate it can be answered in a non-opinionated and helpful way:

> There are reasons why one might want to avoid setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inside a CMakeLists.txt. For one thing, if you're going to do it, you should probably first check that it's not defined (following a general principle of letting the user's choice be respected if they specify something. Setting as a CACHE variable has this behaviour by default), and unless there's some good reason to, you probably should only set it if the current project is the top-level project. Also, I feel like I [keep telling people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549945/11107541) that `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is totally overridable when running `cmake install` by using [`--prefix`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake--install-0). So if you (for some reason) care that what you set in the CMakeLists.txt via `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is actually what gets used when running installation, you'd better keep that in mind.
>
> If the whole reason for wanting to do this is just for convenience for the person running installation and not something *intrinsic to the project itself*, i'd suggest to just stick with using a preset's `installDir`. Especially if it's just for convenience to yourself, use CMakeUserPresets.json.
>
> Also, if you want a preset macro for `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`, you can [raise a feature request issue ticket](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425696/11107541).

If you end up posting this question, please comment here with a link to it. I'd be interested in writing the above as an answer post to it.

---

> Although my specific question is about the CMake install prefix, I wonder if there is a more general rule of thumb how to decide whether to set CMake cache variables in CMakePresets.json vs. CMakeLists.txt?

If you actually want to generalize your question to that level, then you should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/75153894/11107541.

Comment: Given the [corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143040) you found, maybe OP *shouldn't* post anything, as it could only be a duplicate?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if they choose not to generalize the question to how to decide what to put where, and just keep it specific to install prefix, I think that's unique and valuable and appropriate to give a dedicated question post.

Comment: But why? What *specific* insight do you imagine, that doesn't follow from applying the general-case reasoning?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel for one thing, `--prefix`. also specific info about _who you could be inconveniencing by doing a "bad thing", and how it could affect your project. Ex., potentially making it harder for package maintainers like the conan/vcpkg community to work with your package (though I'm not sure if those specific ones would/could be inconvenienced by this).

Comment: also, usage of the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable in a CMakeLists.txt has the downside that it can lead people who don't know about `--prefix` to think they can rely on its value to determine other things. Whereas those people should probably be looking at whether they should be using `$<INSTALL_PREFIX>` or other installation-related generator expressions.

Comment: @starball - recent downvoting/commenting experience has left me reticent about asking questions where an answer might have even a trace of subjectivity. I consider this unfortunate, because Stack Overflow has been an invaluable source of "teaching opportunity," to use your phrase, for me in the past. But I understand that that may have just been an unintentional benefit, counter to Stack Overflow's goals. Thank you for your answer though: it helped me connect the dots between many disparate things I'd learned, but haven't yet been able to put together into a holistic understanding of CMake.

Comment: @StoneThrow also let me know if you end up raising a feature-request issue ticket (with a link to it).

Comment: @StoneThrow also, subjective questions are not banned on SO. read the bottom section of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Even if there are subjective parts to your question (which I don't really think so), I think it'd fall under "constructive-subjective".

Comment: @starball -- I was going to respond at some length on the topic of subjective questions and my recent SO experiences...but I have to fight my tendency to get "chatty" knowing that there's another engaged human in the "conversation." Since you seem to have expertise with CMake, though, I wonder if I might draw your attention to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943274/can-cmakepresets-json-configurepreset-enforce-both-its-condition-and-an-inherite in hopes of more quickly attracting the eyes of a responder open to the "teaching opportunity" approach.

Comment: Meta isn't an appropriate place to provide an answer the question about CMake. Answers here should only address if it's suitable to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sean I answered the question to _demonstrate why_ I believe it's in-scope for SO.

Comment: @starball I've suggested an edit to clarify that